# C++ - error: expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am very new to C++ and I am trying to create a matrix generating function using a double for loop;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

using std::vector;

vector<int> makeMatrix(int xDim, int yDim){
   vector<int> o(xDim,yDim);
   for(int i=0; i<xDim; ++i){
      for(int j=0; j<yDim; ++j){
          o[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
      }   
   }   
   return o;    
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
        const int xDim= 10; 
        const int yDim= 10; 

        auto v1 = makeMatrix(xDim,yDim);

        for ( int x = 0; x < xDim; x ++ ) {
                for ( int y = 0; y < yDim; y++ ) {
                        std::cout << v1[x][y] << " ";
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to see each element so I know what I am doing but I am getting;

```
error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
```

when I try to access them.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` here `vector<int> makeMatrix(int xDim, int yDim)` as return type? Also `vector<int> o(xDim,yDim);` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<int> o(xDim,yDim);` creates a one dimensional vector.  Then `o[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);` attempts to use it as a 2d vector.  Since `o[i]` gives you an `int&` calling `[]` on it will not work as `int` has no `operator[]`.

I think you meant to have

```
vector<vector<int>> o(xDim,vector<int>(yDim));
```

You would also have to change the return type.  That would be

```
vector<vector<int>> makeMatrix(int xDim, int yDim)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> o(xDim,yDim);
```

creates a vector of `int`'s which will contain `xDim`(10) elements with the value of `yDim`(10).

So it will look like this: `{ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }`.

You're trying to create a 2D vector.
You can create one like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> o(xDim, vector<int>(yDim));
```